# Allowing Guests to create records on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I have a guest_user and current_user system with devise that allows guest_users to create orders.  This all works locally.

Although, with heroku i get errors.

The first error i received was because there was no guest_user confirmation.  So i changed `validate: false` to `validate: true`.  Then i still received errors because of the Password.  When i added a password, the app broke.

With a current_user who is signed in, it works fine.  I don't want to change the model to take away confirmations, i want to have it work like it does locally.  Locally, a guest_user can create an order with no errors, then sign up with their orders present (if email matches `order.email`)

**Here's the error when creating an `Order`:**

```
2019-01-21T22:06:15.195141+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-01-21T22:06:15.195016 #4] DEBUG -- : [bcc07ad7-f215-4c19-b442-bdc4677b545e]   [1m[35m (5.4ms)[0m  [1m[31mROLLBACK[0m

2019-01-21T22:06:15.195851+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-01-21T22:06:15.195791 #4]  INFO -- : [bcc07ad7-f215-4c19-b442-bdc4677b545e] Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 41ms (ActiveRecord: 12.3ms)

2019-01-21T22:06:15.196780+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-21T22:06:15.196720 #4] FATAL -- : [bcc07ad7-f215-4c19-b442-bdc4677b545e]   

2019-01-21T22:06:15.196867+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-21T22:06:15.196813 #4] FATAL -- : [bcc07ad7-f215-4c19-b442-bdc4677b545e] ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Password can't be blank):

2019-01-21T22:06:15.196945+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-21T22:06:15.196892 #4] FATAL -- : [bcc07ad7-f215-4c19-b442-bdc4677b545e]   

2019-01-21T22:06:15.197040+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2019-01-21T22:06:15.196983 #4] FATAL -- : [bcc07ad7-f215-4c19-b442-bdc4677b545e] app/controllers/application_controller.rb:84:in `create_guest_user'

2019-01-21T22:06:15.197043+00:00 app[web.1]: [bcc07ad7-f215-4c19-b442-bdc4677b545e] app/controllers/application_controller.rb:40:in `guest_user'

2019-01-21T22:06:15.197045+00:00 app[web.1]: [bcc07ad7-f215-4c19-b442-bdc4677b545e] app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:101:in `create'
```

**Here's the devise code i have in my application controller for use of `guest_user`:**

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:name])
  end

  def current_or_guest_user
    if current_user
      if session[:guest_user_id] && session[:guest_user_id] != current_user.id
        logging_in
        # reload guest_user to prevent caching problems before destruction
        guest_user(with_retry = false).try(:reload).try(:destroy)
        session[:guest_user_id] = nil
      end
      current_user
    else
      guest_user
    end
  end

  # find guest_user object associated with the current session,
  # creating one as needed
  def guest_user(with_retry = true)
    # Cache the value the first time it's gotten.
    @cached_guest_user ||= User.find(session[:guest_user_id] ||= create_guest_user.id)

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound # if session[:guest_user_id] invalid
     session[:guest_user_id] = nil
     guest_user if with_retry
  end


  private
  def logging_in
    guest_orders = guest_user.orders.all?
    guest_orders.each do |order|
      order.user_id = current_user.id
      order.save!
    end


  end

  def create_guest_user
    u = User.new(:name => "guest", :email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(100)}@example.com")
    u.save!(:validate => true)
    session[:guest_user_id] = u.id
    u
  end
```

**Previously i had** `u.save!(:validate => false)` but got errors due to no confirmation --- this did work locally though.

**I tried** adding `:password => "#{Time.now.to_i}"` and `:password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64`  but then the heroku server wouldn't work at all.

What can I do to allow the guest_user to create orders without these issues the same way it works locally?

User model:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :confirmable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
          :trackable


    after_create :connect_orders

        def active_for_authentication?
          super && approved
        end

        def inactive_message
          approved? ? super : :not_approved
        end

  def connect_orders
    Order.where(email: self.email).update_all(buyer_id: self.id)
  end
```

**Within my create method in the OrdersController I have:**

```
if user_signed_in?
  @order.buyer_id = current_user.id
else
  @order.buyer_id = guest_user.id
end
```

So i need an id for a buyer.  What's confusing is this all works locally just not working Heroku

Comment: Why exactly are you storing your guest user to the DB?

Comment: so when they make a purchase they can create an account to transfer the information over.

Comment: can you share your user.rb model?

Comment: Added the user model for all devise related

Comment: Feels like a square peg in a round hole. I would store the info in a redis db if you don't want to store it all in a cookie

Comment: i used the code devise suggested/provided in their docs for allowing guests to be users.  But would using redis help this situation and how?  i really ultimately want non signed in users to be able to create Order records

Comment: By removing `:confirmable` from the model, i was able to get it to work with gues users.  although, i do need confirmable to work.  I don't know why it tries to confirm when i create an order but local it does not

Comment: Update: ended up being my mail server wasn't full set up or correctly set up.  When it would attempt to send the email, it wasn't able to.  now it works and with confirmable